# Zod custom validation

Tags: reactjs, typescript, validation, zod

I'm trying to add some custom validation to my validation schema on zod (react + typescript).

Currently this is my approach:

```
export const validationSchema = (type: string) => {
  let dictOfValidations: { [key: string]: any } = {};

  BasicOperationSchema.forEach((field) => {
    if (!field.shouldRender || field.shouldRender(type)) {
      switch (field.type) {
        case "string":
          dictOfValidations[field.name] = z
            .string()
            .min(1, { message: field.msgError });
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
    }
  });

  return object(dictOfValidations).superRefine((data, ctx) => {
    if (hasValidScheme(data.productScheme)) {
      ctx.addIssue({
        code: z.ZodIssueCode.custom,
        message: "Product scheme is invalid!",
      });
    }

    if (hasNHRNFormat(data.productNHRN)) {
      ctx.addIssue({
        code: z.ZodIssueCode.custom,
        message: "Product NHRN is invalid!",
      });
    }
  });
};
```

The issue is like follows. I have an utils class with the validation for some specific fields but this superRefine doesn't seem to work.

Do you see anything that Im missing?

I expected the form to set the errors on screen for my custom validations. However, it renders the submit without preventing it from sending to the backend.